# A more efficient way of finding value in dictionary and its position

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains (roughly) 6 elements, each of an element which looks like the following:

What I want to do is find a particular domain (that I pass through a method) and if it exists, it stores the keyword and its position within an object. I have tried the following

```
def parseGoogleResponse(response, website):

    i = 0 
    for item in response['items']:
      if(item['formattedUrl'] == website):
           print i 
           break; 
      i++
```

This approach seems to be a bit tedious and also `i` also remains the same at `i = 10` and I'm pretty sure that this is a more efficient way. I also have to keep in consideration that if the website is not found the first time, it then queries the API for a maximum up to 5 pages, each page contains 6 search results so I somehow have to calculate the position if it is on a different page.

Any ideas

Comment: You can’t search an arbitrarily-ordered list faster than that.

Comment: the `keyword` argument is not used in your function, what is `keyword` ?
Also, show how should look the expected result for those 6 items

Comment: python != c++... `i++` is a syntax error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok but even with i + 1 still just throws up 10. I need a way of being able to determine what position the website was found in

Comment: Can you please edit your dictionary so it's not so long. Just post a minimal dictionary that conveys your point.

Comment: one more time: *show how should look the expected result for those 6 items*

Comment: Are you sure you're just not finding anything? I don't understand. Again, you have a syntax error, but apparently your code is running, so I have no idea what you've actually got. In any event, the pythonic way to iterate with a count is to do `for i, item in enumerate(response['items']):`

Comment: And for the love of Guido, man, don't end lines with semicolons and don't put extraneous parentheses around conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python are not ordered.  There is no way to find something's position in a dictionary, unlike `list` type objects.

You can rather easily check for the existence of a value in the dictionary with something like:

```
if website in response['items'].values():
    # If you enter this section, you know it's in the dictionary
else:
    # If you end up here, it isn't in the dictionary
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - How can I do this so that the responses are in the order they are coming from? I am using googleapiclient and this is for tracking keyword ranking

Comment: In the collections module, you'll find `OrderedDict`. This is a pluggable replacement for standard `dict`,  except that it also maintains its items in the order in which they are created.